# How can you set ESLint CLI settings in configuration file?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I'm trying to set [`max-warnings`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#max-warnings) in my `.eslintrc.js` file. But the documentation discusses it as a Command Line Interface option. Is there a way to set this within my configuration file as opposed to the CLI option?

Comment: I would love to do the same with `--fix`. Did you ever find a way?

Comment: Seems like this won't be possible anytime soon: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/16804#issuecomment-1460887876

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a tag for the config file where you can specify max-warnings.

The next closest thing is to add a script to your package.json, provided you have one:

```
  "scripts": {
    "eslint": "eslint . --max-warnings {amount}"
  }
```

If this isn't an option for you, you could create a script file that runs the command above when you call it. Otherwise, an [enhancement ticket](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues) is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search for similar configuration but haven't find any. Ended up with following work around code.

```js
const results = await eslint.lintFiles(['src/**']);
const warningCount = results.reduce((c, i) => c + i.warningCount, 0);

// Logic to exist process for non zero warning count.
if(warningCount) {
  process.exitCode = 1;
  console.error(`ESLint found too many warnings (count: ${warningCount}).`);
}
```